# How to bypass model jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am looking to get a case where the `ModelState.IsValid` returns false.

I am using validation attributes on my MVC Model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="The Title is Requiered")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]        
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

The client side is validated with the default MVC 3 jquery libraries.

Things I tryed to remove the validation from busting my errors :

- Inspect source and remove all jquery references when page is loaded
- Add class="cancel" on my input submit
- Add a onsubmit="return true;" on my form
- Jump 10 times on one leg, while holding a cup of coffee
- Remove all class and attributes related to validation from the input I'm trying to bypass

Still can't get the page to post back the invalid form content.

Comment: Turn off clientside validation (temporarily) in your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Set "ClientValidationEnabled" to false in the "appSettings" section of your Web.config file.